# Drawing a rectangle with asterisks using methods and loops

Tags: java, loops, methods, ascii-art

I have been trying to create a rectangle that looks like this:

```
*****
*   *
*****
```

or this:

```
************
*          *
************
```

depending on the number that I input. I can't seem to get it right. This is what I have so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrawRectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer greater 1 for the length");
        int length = keyboard.nextInt();

        int rectangle = draw_rectangle(length);
        System.out.print(rectangle);
    }

    public static int draw_rectangle(int m) {
        for (int star = 2; star <= m; star++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("*\f   *\f\r\n");
        for (int star = 2; star <= m; star++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        return (m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you start both loops with `2`?

Comment: Because the person using the program has to input a length greater than 1.

Comment: That is not a good reason. Think about *how many* stars need printing.

Comment: So you know that the number of stars on the first line is that of the int entered as length. Therefore the rectangle has a length of **m** and **m** stars need to be printed in the first and last lines. Only 2 need to be printed in the middle line and the remaining *m-2* characters on that line in between are whitespaces.

Comment: Yeah I realized after reviewing it, that it wasn't necessary for my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are just trying to create a method that prints a rectangle with N length.
First off, this method does not need to return an int, it can just be void. At the end of the main method, you are printing *rectangle*, which is the same value of *length*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrawRectangle{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer greater 1 for the length");
        int length = keyboard.nextInt();
        draw_rectangle(length);
        // This was rectangle but will print
        // out whatever int the user entered
        System.out.print(length);
    }
    public static void draw_rectangle(int m) {
        for(int star = 0; star < m; star++) System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print("\n*");
        for(int space = 0; space < m-2; space++) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print("*\n");
        for(int star = 0; star < m; star++) System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You will take note of changes in the drawing of the rectangle. The first line is of **m** `*`s and the next line contains of 2 of `*` and **m-2** whitespaces. The line following is just like the first. Take note that loops from *0 to m-1* will iterate m times. You should send this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for more helpful tips.

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure why you're starting the loops with 2, or what the middle print is trying to do, but here's how I'd do it:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == m)
            System.out.print("*");
        else if (j == 0 || j == m)
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method for printing *rectangles* and an additional one for printing *squares* as a special case of a previous one, where the *width* is twice the *height* for correct display.

Output:

```
******
*    *
******

************
*          *
************
```

Code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSquare(3, ' ', '*');
    System.out.println();
    printRectangle(3, 12, ' ', '*');
}
```

```java
public static void printSquare(int size, char fill, char border) {
    printRectangle(size, size * 2, fill, border);
}
```

```java
public static void printRectangle(int height, int width, char fill, char border) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == height - 1 || j == width - 1) {
                System.out.print(border);
            } else {
                System.out.print(fill);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Display squares of asterisks, filled and hollow, side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66226533/14940971)</sup>