# Display squares of asterisks, filled and hollow, side by side

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops, ascii-art

I'm currently trying to display a filled asterisk square and a hollow asterisk :

```
********** **********
********** *        *
********** *        *
********** *        *
********** **********
```

Instead, I'm getting this output:

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

I'm not so sure how to make it side by side instead of up and down. Do I have to put the hollow nested loop inside the filled loop or do I have to do something else? Here is my code:

```java
public class doubleNestedLoops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Filled Square
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Hollow Square
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == 5 || i == 1 || i == 10) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Martinez' answer works fine, but it's a little inefficient. I'll put a step by step below your code, which I revamped:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Both Squares
        StringBuilder filledLine = new StringBuilder(10);
        StringBuilder hollowLine = new StringBuilder(10);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                filledLine.append("*");
                if (i == 1 || i == 5 || j == 1 || j == 10) {
                    hollowLine.append("*");
                } else {
                    hollowLine.append(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(filledLine + " " + hollowLine);
            filledLine.delete(0, filledLine.length());
            hollowLine.delete(0, hollowLine.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Step 1: Convert your two loops to one loop. This is because you cannot print on the same line once you've made a new line.

Step2: Because we'll be using Strings in a loop, it's more efficient to use a `StringBuffer`, so we don't constantly make new strings

Step 3: Write all of the output from your logic to the buffers instead of the console.

Step 4: Print the buffers one line at a time, as we fill them.

Step 5: Profit!

Answer (score 1):

After you print a line, you cannot go back to the line that was printed and add more * to it. This means that after you print a line for the filled square, you can't go back to the same line that was already printed to add the *s for the hollow square.

The easiest way to resolve this is to restructure your code a bit so that instead of printing first the filled square and the hollow one afterwards, you print both at the same time on each line.

To do this, you could restructure your code to something like this:

```
//Loop through each line that needs to be printed
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

   //Loop through characters for filled square needed in this line
   for(int j=0; j< ; j++){
       //Add print logic for filled square
   }

   //Loop through characters for hollow square on the same line
   for(int j=1; j<=5; j++){
       //Add print logic for hollow square
   }

   System.out.println();//Go to next line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write *a more generic* method for printing squares like this:

```
**********  **********  **********  **********  **********  **********  **********
**********  *        *  *        *  **********  *        *  *        *  **********
**********  *        *  *        *  **********  *        *  *        *  **********
**********  *        *  *        *  **********  *        *  *        *  **********
**********  **********  **********  **********  **********  **********  **********
```

```
******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
*      * ******** *      * *      * ******** *      *
*      * ******** *      * *      * ******** *      *
******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
```

```
line1: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], size: 5
line2: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], size: 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVNc5swEL37V2x9ggQT25NccJNOp9NDD50e0lsmBwFrIyIkIol43CS/3V3x5bSGOBobxGr3afX2LeTsic1UiTJPH/Z7XpRKW8jJGFaWi/BsNTmyGauRFeE3JQQmVmkz7vND2tt6tppMyioWPIFEMGPgJ@MSnidAo7UbyyzdnhRPoaBVjwK53NzdA9Mb47fObnBpa6tewDU8LwKY17/D5HV17Lt0vv940ZUce8@vWrOdaRP3BJfouS0CuApgCjD1/XCt9HeWZN7tzlgsQlXZKCopSSukvzoBtAzg0gGdxumBDsthu@pNHdwiIpzzbh@rGqLqbH2yTwMw/A82TldvEhvDW47iLY/wLlu818lA7fqK1YfuqQ9cFWqMoHWBFAUvuEX9tq4abaXlf/xRvN97dOPiAkqNJdMIDMxj5SZEKiCxCrIqYtTRUNAcZpCRbNUWmExhQY9rTipOh5wb4X7uDnVz5BMWrPytfsW5x2F20@bhNefk8Oka5v5g6gYfK5SWMyF2kCtqhCbUEEcpzuLdzN2HIrfcZmAzBFNiwtcc0wOTEKPdIkq3XhznqjGtEvRaTTe1paT7Bg01kxv05k2xj/MeObSDu@P3pIxDIuc1PFnfQbGqLnPf5FEkcTtAV0itIgx6shLiQ9Jrq3BQXKyUQCbbQg/o7cMUUAG4ExDyTWYDyGm@5anNTgljZAM4g@U4Q7SZK3STdadxJ1pnjZVOURtQ6/qxkfR7UF28@9NLQHPzYAJQFKy33CBsM6qcKVmC5gOVz92p2sxeXoiUa9K6m@X1bBShG11MzcKM2rAL7WipjV9gejaFqH5njieVNF8h7/A1Cl1LuReYP6SnYeF1ynrd7/8C)

The *line* of squares is defined as an `int[]` array, where the squares are: `0` - hollow and `1` - filled. Each *square* is a `String[]` array of a specified `size`, where each string is twice as long as a specified `size`. The squares are sequentially joined to each other *side-by-side* with the specified `delimiter` between them.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1};
    int[] arr2 = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};

    Arrays.stream(line(arr1, 5, "  ")).forEach(System.out::println);
    Arrays.stream(line(arr2, 4, " ")).forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("line1: " + Arrays.toString(arr1) + ", size: " + 5);
    System.out.println("line2: " + Arrays.toString(arr2) + ", size: " + 4);
}
```

```java
public static String[] line(int[] arr, int size, String delimiter) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            // prepare a square for each number:
            // 0 - hollow and 1 - filled
            // Stream<String[]>
            .mapToObj(i -> square(size, i != 0))
            // sequentially join squares side-by-side
            // with the specified delimiter between them
            .reduce((arr1, arr2) -> IntStream.range(0, size)
                    .mapToObj(i -> arr1[i] + delimiter + arr2[i])
                    .toArray(String[]::new))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

```java
public static String[] square(int size, boolean filled) {
    return IntStream.range(0, size)
            // i - height, j - width
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, size * 2)
                    // the filled square and the borders of the hollow
                    // square are asterisks, otherwise whitespaces
                    .mapToObj(j -> filled || i == 0 || j == 0
                            || i == size - 1 || j == size * 2 - 1 ? "*" : " ")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining()))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```