# Printing a checkerboard or square pattern

Tags: java, for-loop, ascii-art

I'm learning Java and I'm currently trying to make some ASCII art with the program. I was able to make a hollow diamond, but I'm struggling with creating a "checkerboard" or square pattern. I'm trying to create something that looks like this:

```
***    ***    ***
***    ***    ***
```

For some reason it keeps coming out like this:

```
***
***
   ***
***
```

I know the issue is with my for-loop. Since I just learned about nested loops, I'm still trying to understand the logic. My middle loop controls the spaces, and no matter what value I put for `s` (my incrementing variable), it still makes the pattern come out weird.

Here is my code:

```java
public class ASCII_Art {
    public static void squares() {
        System.out.println("***\n***   ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < i - 4; y++) {
                squares();
                System.out.print("   ");
                squares();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made a square method since I read that methods make everything clearer and easier since you don't have to rewrite the same code multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the problem here is that your square method prints out three asterisks and then goes to a new line. You then can't go back to the previous line, which is why the first square looks good, but then the others look out of place. If you look at the output, the first square is being printed. You then print the white-spaces and then another square. But this second square does not start on the first line. It starts on the second, so what ends up happening is the first three asterisks are printed, and then \n tells it to go to a new line, and then the other three asterisks are printed which is why they look separated. Like other people have suggested, use \t, not \n.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. As others have pointed out, `\n` creates a new line,
   like so. `\t` on the other hand, creates an indent,       like so. For your purposes, `\t` is what you want.
2. In your `squares` function, you only print two `***`s. Instead, print 3.
3. Since `squares` already prints one line, you only need a single for loop going up to 2. The conventional way to do this is `int i = 0; i < 2`.

Below is the full corrected code (I fixed the indentation, rebracketed, and added a `main` method):

```java
public class ASCII_Art
{   
    public static void squares(){
        System.out.println("***\t***\t***");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            squares();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since your `squares` method doesn't actually provide much value, you could just do this instead:

```java
public class ASCII_Art
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("***\t***\t***");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to customize your ASCII art further, you could make a function taking 3 parameters: one for number of `*`s, one for number of asterisk blocks in one line, and one for number of lines. I'll let you figure that out yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize a *checkerboard* as a `Boolean[][]` matrix `8x8`, where each element is:

```java
m[i][j] = (i - j) % 2 != 0;
```

Then you can represent each `Boolean` as a filled or hollow *square*, then join these squares side-by-side into a single *line*, and then output them line-by-line.

```
    ****    ****    ****    ****
    ****    ****    ****    ****
****    ****    ****    ****    
****    ****    ****    ****    
    ****    ****    ****    ****
    ****    ****    ****    ****
****    ****    ****    ****    
****    ****    ****    ****    
    ****    ****    ****    ****
    ****    ****    ****    ****
****    ****    ****    ****    
****    ****    ****    ****    
    ****    ****    ****    ****
    ****    ****    ****    ****
****    ****    ****    ****    
****    ****    ****    ****
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVXLbtswELz7K7YGCkiurKQ@FXKToi166CHoIb0ZPlDS2qJCkQpJJXCLfLu71Cs2LDtCdRFBDfcxs0Pl7InNVYkyTx/2e16USlvIaTOsLBfhbDk52TNWIyvC70oITKzS5jzmp7T39Wo5mZRVLHgCiWDGwB3jEv5OgJ5231hm6fWkeAoFffXoIJfb1RqY3hq/Bbvn6go2HEUKhv/BfpdLCxJu4NPyEGgeK6bxFGkIuThCqsqWlQUGSYbJA@pYMZ32gL6RUDO5Re86AOn3Xw/CcJhDhnyb2QByWj/z1GZDwFJj6UpjoNUzqA3ESglk0gyBm9yfvzWQ1fr2BBQWrPytfsW5RxXcjqz3iFFSMwWlISNdqaI5WF2h29gwYfDs2dfEuUvs0kPuw3tYwLsbuD6fNLTqq9Zs5/VdRZHEZ9@/zJbgEh1djbIGNlQhsiRzNF6grpumYeY8pwFV74K7dQBmuI6jaAOxNoLZO4pXd2aiqPHBYKh24Op@4l39Hoin9A9qzrvfGYtFSGeiqKTcVki/Gd@XyYCLeu/UDfUEk5V00Mw/GeLQUxptpSU0Zbfu9Qj9hhitvXoNUGCB0v6/Ds4ETogmsOfKDGpnDMth8LGifJwJsYNc0Z3SjYXhKc7j3dy9T1NpTKsEPdfhx8CxsvDPuKYmasTw165z4VZ8DR/qkLQaMf0dIeeGP6QJIP95shJilOQtdZ3KQXextBYfUH1026Pvt7dvI5cAZrDwx14s7QX1BaazKUQwhemFo0nzb/Je/1Ghmw4iyPOHOB4Wo2P7Zb//Bw)

Three methods: to create *squares* of spaces and asterisks, to create *lines* of squares, and to output a *field* of lines.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // field size
    int n = 8;
    // square size
    int s = 2;
    // output a checkerboard
    IntStream.range(0, n)
            // i - height, j - width
            // prepare a row of booleans
            // Stream<Boolean[]>
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                    // filled or hollow - true or false
                    .mapToObj(j -> (i - j) % 2 != 0)
                    .toArray(Boolean[]::new))
            // prepare a line of squares for each row
            // Stream<String[]>
            .map(row -> line(row, s))
            // Stream<String>
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            // output line by line
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

```
public static String[] line(Boolean[] arr, int size) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            // prepare a square for each element
            // Stream<String[]>
            .map(bool -> square(size, bool))
            // sequentially join squares side-by-side
            .reduce((arr1, arr2) -> IntStream.range(0, size)
                    .mapToObj(i -> arr1[i] + arr2[i])
                    .toArray(String[]::new))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

```
public static String[] square(int size, boolean filled) {
    return IntStream.range(0, size)
            // i - height, j - width
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, size * 2)
                    .mapToObj(j -> filled ? "*" : " ")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining()))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Display squares of asterisks, filled and hollow, side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66226533/15402945)</sup>