# Reverse "staircase" with for loop in java graphics (JFrame)

Tags: java, loops, swing, graphics, jframe

I have the code below, which makes a staircase in java with a for loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    g.drawRect(5, 5 + 10 * i, 10 + 10 * i, 10);
}
```

But I want the same thing, but backwards, upside down, and reversed, like the image below:

[image]

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent a staircase as a 2d array of `0` and `1` in some of its corner. Then you can iterate over this array and for each number print a *filled* or *hollow* square.

For example, a 2d array with a staircase in the *lower right corner*:

```java
int m = 5;
int[][] staircase = IntStream.range(0, m)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, m)
                //.map(j -> i >= j ? 1 : 0) // lower left
                //.map(j -> i <= j ? 1 : 0) // upper right
                //.map(j -> i + j < m ? 1 : 0) // upper left
                .map(j -> i + j >= m - 1 ? 1 : 0) // lower right
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(staircase).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Display squares of asterisks, *filled* and *hollow*, side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66226533/15309136)</sup>